# Getting "Message from debugger: Error 1" - for simple project (in Xcode 11.0 11A420a)

Tags: c, xcode, debugging

my code is simple like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    
    printf(" sizeof int = %lu\n", sizeof(int));
    
    return 0;
}
```

run on xcode and got error:

```
Message from debugger: Error 1
Program ended with exit code: -1
```

[image: img2]

run Terminal :

[image: img3]

Comment: Please do not post code as images - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question.

Comment: This started happening to me a few days ago in Xcode 11 and I have absolutely no idea why. In my case it might be related to having to revoke a certificate at around the same time.

Comment: This should be marked as duplicate since the other questions are dealing w more complex cases.

Comment: I've had related problems to this, in my case it was because I was using an old version of macOS and Xcode, that didn't have the newer Apple Worldwide Developer Relations certificate installed.

You can install it yourself by downloading it from https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/.

Answer (score 3):

Tap PROJECT settings Signing & Capabilities, in Signing - Signing Certificate, if your selected is "Development", you can change it to "Sign to Run Locally" to have a try.

If you don't have a development certification, you can not be coding with that certificate mode.

Comment: This would work, but **just if we do NOT use specific capabilities (like Network-Extension), which are available to Paid Apple-ID only.**

Answer (score 0):

The code that you've posted runs fine for me in an Xcode 12 project configured as a command line tool. Here's the output:

```
Hello, World!
 sizeof int = 4
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Try pasting the same code into a new project, and again, set it up as a command line tool. You shouldn't need to make any changes to the project default settings. If it works, compare that to your original project; the reason for the failure is somewhere in the original project's configuration.

Answer (score 0):

From: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1884/_index.html

**Q:  When I run my Mac app, it crashes immediately, and the crash log says Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid). What is going on here?**

A: The crash log indicates that your app is signed with your Mac App Store distribution identity, with the certificate’s Subject Common Name starting with “3rd Party Mac Developer Application.” Mac apps signed this way can no longer be run directly. Here’s the background on this.

Over time, more Mac App Store technologies have been added that require entitlements that come from a provisioning profile. This started with push notifications and iCloud. Later, Game Center and Maps were added to the list.

Recently, the `com.apple.developer.team-identifier` entitlement was added to all new Mac provisioning profiles. This means that, going forward, distribution builds of Mac apps cannot be run directly; they are for submitting to iTunes Connect for app review only

Instead, developers should adopt the Archive Build Workflow in [QA1778: How to reproduce bugs reported against Mac App Store submissions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1778/_index.html) for testing the builds that they plan to submit for the Mac App Store. On Xcode 6, select `Export as a Mac Application`. You won't see any chance to select your development signing identity, but Xcode will export the app from the archive as it was signed at build time. So the result will be the same.

You can create an installer package containing your development-signed app by hand with the `productbuild` tool, like this:

```
$ productbuild --component Sample.app /Applications --sign “3rd Party Mac Developer Installer:" Sample.pkg
```

Then install the package as documented in [Testing the Mac Installer Package](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/SubmittingYourApp/SubmittingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH9-SW40):

```
$ sudo installer -store -pkg Sample.pkg -target /
```

This workflow means that you will need to add your beta testers’ test systems to your Mac Developer Program account so they will be able to run your app.

Another possibility is to use `Xcode Organizer > Export > Export a Developer ID-signed Application`. Developer ID-signed apps can be run by anyone. However, code that uses technologies only available to Mac App Store apps, such as receipt validation, iCloud, and push notifications, will not work if your app is Developer ID-signed. You might need to temporarily disable those parts of your app if you opt for the Developer ID testing approach.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem, which is very disturbing.

[screenshot-img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDnRW.png)

These settings solve my problem. You can have a try.

Comment: You should explain more about why you feel this may solve the question.

Comment: Wonderful that fixed it for me, thanks.

Comment: This would work, but **just if we do NOT use specific capabilities (like Network-Extension), which are available to Paid Apple-ID only.**